# Is there a term for the study of asteroids?

Tags: terminology, soft-question, asteroids

I'm trying to find the name for the academic specialty of studying asteroids, but I can't seem to find any. For example, there is a distinct wikipedia page for "Planet" vs "Planetary science". Is there no asteroidology? Does no one have a PhD in asteroid sciences? Are asteroids actually not interesting enough to have their own subfield? Does it get wrapped into planetary science?